# How to retrieve read-only attributes from ldap using Spring

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I need to access some read only attributes into spring code and use them. however I'm not even able to read those attributes from LDAP . Tried using attribute mapper and context mapper but no use. Any other way is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read-only attributes should be returned by default. Operational attributes are a different matter: they need to be asked for explicitly. Try using one of the methods that allow you to specify the attributes to return, e.g. [this one](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-ldap/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapOperations.html#lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper-).

Comment: Thank you :) Set up Search Controls with my search and it works fine now :D